# Hibernate ManyToOne referencing an object with a column (unique=true)?

Tags: sql, hibernate

I have a Job class like the following

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public int getId() {
    return Id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    Id = id;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
@NotNull
@JoinColumn(name="job_type_id")
public JobType getJobType() {
    return jobType;
}

public void setJobType(JobType jobType) {
    this.jobType = jobType;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
@NotNull
@JoinColumn(name="job_status_id")
public JobStatus getJobStatus() {
    return jobStatus;
}
public void setJobStatus(JobStatus jobStatus) {
    this.jobStatus = jobStatus;
}


@Column(name="priority",nullable=false)
public int getPriority() {
    return priority;
}
public void setPriority(int priority) {
    this.priority = priority;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
@NotNull
@JoinColumn(name="applliaction_id")
public Application getApplication() {
    return application;
}
public void setApplication(Application application) {
    this.application = application;
}
```

}

And the JobStatus class is like

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name="name",nullable =false, unique=true, length=50)
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Column(name="description",columnDefinition = "text")
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}
public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
```

and JobType class like

```
    @Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name="name", unique=true, nullable=false,length=20)
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Column(name="description",columnDefinition = "text")
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}
public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
```

and Application class like

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name="name",nullable=false,unique =true, length=50)
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Column(name="current_version",nullable=false,length=50)
public String getCurretnVersion() {
    return curretnVersion;
}
public void setCurretnVersion(String curretnVersion) {
    this.curretnVersion = curretnVersion;
}

@Column(name="updated_at",nullable=false)
public Date getUpdatedAt() {
    return updatedAt;
}
public void setUpdatedAt(Date updatedAt) {
    this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
}

@Column(name="created_at",nullable=false)
public Date getCreatedAt() {
    return createdAt;
}
public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
    this.createdAt = createdAt;
}
@Column(name="description",columnDefinition = "text")
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}
public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
```

And the main method is like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println((new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss:SSS")).format(new Date()));      
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    System.out.println((new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss:SSS")).format(new Date()));

    //Application
    Application app = new Application();
    app.setName("GW");
    app.setCreatedAt(new Date());
    app.setUpdatedAt(new Date());
    app.setCurretnVersion("1.0");

    //Job Type
    JobType jType = new JobType();
    jType.setDescription("new type");
    jType.setName("banboo");

    //Job Status
    JobStatus js = new JobStatus();
    js.setName("waiting");


    //first job
    Job job1 = new Job();
    job1.setPriority(3);        
    job1.setApplication(app);
    job1.setJobType(jType);
    job1.setJobStatus(js);

    //Second Job
    Job job2 = new Job();
    job2.setPriority(3);
    job2.setApplication(app);
    job2.setJobStatus(js);
    job2.setJobType(jType);

    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(job1);
    session.save(job2);
    session.save(jType);
    session.save(js);
    session.save(app);
    tx.commit();
    session.close();
    System.out.println((new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss:SSS")).format(new Date()));
}
```

First time I ran the main is OK. But when I rerun it. Got the following error.
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "uk_jidxac21t4vg1tmees14dwyo1"
Detail: Key (name)=(banboo) already exists.

how to solve the problem?

Thanks,

Scott

Edit the program and question as JB Nizet suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You told Hibernate that the association is a `OneToOne`.

That means that only one Job may reference a given JobStatus, and that only one JobStatus can be referenced by a given Job.

If you want many jobs to share one JobStatus, you need a `ManyToOne`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I got almost the same problem after changing to ManyToOne. The problem is from unique=true in JobStatus. Some how  the program tries to enter the same JobStatus two times.

Comment: If you want a job to reference a JobStatus that already exists, you need to get this JobStatus from the database (by ID, using session.get() or session.load(), or by another criterion, using a query). You can't just create a new JobStatus with the same name as an existing one, and hope that Hibernate will magically find the existing job status having this name and set it in the job for you.